# How to get OpenResult from IRP_MJ_CREATE callback?

Tags: c, windows, filesystems, kernel, driver

I have an event in process monitor and I am trying to get `OpenResult` value.

[image: Process monitor CreateFile OpenResult]

I have a callback registered and triggered on `IRP_MJ_CREATE`, it looks like this

```
ULONG CreateOperationCallback(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjs)
{       
    if(Data->IoStatus.Status & FILE_CREATE)
    {
        DBGLOG("File created"); // :( not hit in the debugger 
    }

    if(Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options & FILE_CREATE)         
    {
        DBGLOG("File created"); // :( not hit in the debugger 
    }
}
```

**Question:** How to I get `OpenResult` value from my callback method?

Comment: Hopefully it is post-operation, ought to be data->IoStatus.Status

Comment: @HansPassant you were very close. It is set in `IoStatus->Information` and only available in the post-operation callback. Partly, my problem was that I looked at the pre-operation callback and it wasn't available there. Tnx for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for IRP_MJ_CREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `IoStatus->Information` member will be set to one of:

```
FILE_CREATED
FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
FILE_EXISTS
FILE_OPENED
FILE_OVERWRITTEN
FILE_SUPERSEDED
```

Comment: You were right, tnx. This was super helpful. This information is set in the **post** operation callback. But it is not set for the **pre** operation callback.

Comment: At that point, Windows has no way of knowing what the result will be.